# fyne GUI compile to Web Assembly failed

Tags: go, webassembly, fyne

i was checking the possibility to use fyne in browser using Web Assembly , but i am getting  error ...
main.go :

```
package main

import (
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/app"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/container"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/widget"
)

func main() {
    a := app.New()
    w := a.NewWindow("Hello")

    hello := widget.NewLabel("Hello Fyne!")
    w.SetContent(container.NewVBox(
        hello,
        widget.NewButton("Hi!", func() {
            hello.SetText("Welcome :)")
        }),
    ))

    w.ShowAndRun()
}
```

i ran this command ,

```
GOOS=js GOARCH=wasm go build -o main.wasm main.go
```

Output (error) :

```
package command-line-arguments
    imports fyne.io/fyne/v2/app
    imports fyne.io/fyne/v2/internal/driver/glfw
    imports fyne.io/fyne/v2/internal/driver/common
    imports fyne.io/fyne/v2/internal/painter/gl
    imports github.com/go-gl/gl/v3.2-core/gl: build constraints exclude all Go files in /home/ahmed/go/pkg/mod/github.com/go-gl/gl@v0.0.0-20210813123233-e4099ee2221f/v3.2-core/gl
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fyne does not yet support web assembly or delivering through a browser. You can watch our Tech Preview video from FyneConf last week to get an update on this work.
https://youtu.be/t8gEzPujIVI

Comment: It has since been released :) just use “fyne serve” on any release since v2.2.0

Answer (score 3):

The ability to run in a browser is now in testing. You can use the Fyne `develop` branch and install that version of the `fyne` tool, then run:

`$ fyne serve`

It will load your Fyne app via a web server on port :8080.